# Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless Problem! Dell Inspiron 1564

Tags: wireless

I have an problem with the wireless driver on my laptop: I can see other topics about this but they're not very helpful.
The most popular is installing with software & update/ Additional Drivers but it doesn't work.

See screenshot below:

[image: Software&updates screenshot])

I think this is my driver but I can't install it

http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Welcome to askubuntu!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score -1):

Your wireless may not work on this type of issue too. Before installing a ubuntu OS on to your pc check the property of your processor. if the processor is 64-bit based then download 64-bit os. Don't download a 32-bit os. As the hardware inside your pc are 64-bit based. 32-bit os may struggle to open them. This is how i managed to make my wireless work.

Comment: It would be nice if you elaborated why you think this is the case.